# angular 5: interchange locations of dynamic components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I want to interchange the positions of the dynamically placed components inside the view.

i.e. I have created components dynamically with id = 1 and 2 as shown in figure.

[image]

now I need to interchange the positions of both the components but how?

One thing I know (only theoratically) is location can be change through move method inside the `ViewContainerRef class` via object as `viewContainerRef.move(componentRef.hostView, index)`.

I tried it but positions didn't interchange.

```
@ViewChild(ContainerRefDirective) location: ContainerRefDirective;

let componentFactory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(EntryComponent);
let componentRef = this.location.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

let entryComponent: EntryComponent = componentRef.instance;
// lets say counter is variable that increments its value on new component creation.
entryComponent.Id = ++counter; 

// move method is being called right after a new component is created and placed. 
//this piece of code is in the same method (that is creating the dynamic components)
this.location.viewContainerRef.move(componentRef.hostView, 1);
```

I have read the ViewContainerRef documentation on [angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) and read almost same question regarding this issue but could not understand or resolve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved this problem.

#### What I did?

> I changed the values, instead of interchanging the components' locations
>
> i.e. I replaced the values `1 <=> 2` and it looked like components are interchanged.

#### How?

```
// array to hold the newly created component instances
entryComponents: EntryComponent[] = new Array<EntryComponent>();
```

Then push the newly created component into that array

```
let factoryResolver = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(EntryComponent);    
let componentRef = this.location.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factoryResolver);

this.entryComponents.push(componentRef.instance); // getting components' instances
```

Now interchange the values of so that components may look like interchanged.

Thanks **@ForestG**, for this suggestion

Comment: Hello! I wonder why you could not simply edit the other answer, as it was the basis for this? It would be prudent to clean up a little, and maybe credit Forest for his good answer.

Comment: I appreciate his effort but his answer is totally different and was not useful in my case. One of his comments he said to change the object values instead of object location.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you bind your two dynamic component to an array?
for example, if you have an "objectA", and "objectB":

```
this.renderArray.push(objectA);
..
this.renderArray.push(objectB);
```

and your html looks like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let renderObject of renderArray">
   <<you can reference objectA and objectB by using "renderObject.value" etc.>>
</ng-container>
```

when you need to interchange their positions, you just need to manipulate the array and angular does care of the rest:

```
this.renderArray = this.renderArray.reverse();
```

It will re-render the ngFor containers in a new order. 
See [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9rSEwrujDc5duQ3NSSAE).

Comment: does it not possible with `ViewContainerRef.move(ref, index)` method to interchange the positions of dynamic components. If it is, then how?

Comment: I have added components according to your description but now there is an unexpected error `Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError`. Though I had already added this component in `entryComponents`.

Comment: why do you need to handle the component references in the control class? If possible, you should aim for letting that being handled by the angular render engine. Just focus on the data, and bind accordingly. So instead of binding the Components, bind the Data, that is _on the component_. (If you are using dynamic component binding, than my approach is not useable I am afraid)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions. I changed the values instead of changing the component locations and it gave me my result.

Comment: Do you still need help? Just noticed the bounty on the question.

Comment: Yes, I want to know the use of move method in ViewContainerRef that what is its basic use and how it can be used. Does its use to change the locations of components, if yes then how because I tried to interchange the components through this method but in vain.

Comment: would you mind to get bounty by answering my question?

Comment: Honestly, I suggested a different core logic concept about rendering your components, instead of the ViewContainerRef.move method. I have no clue about how to achive this and to be even more honest, don't really uderstand your further questions. Sorry about that.

Comment: Simple, I only need the purpose and use of `move` method.
Forget about rest of the things.

Comment: I guess that the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) did not help?

Comment: yes, it didn't help me or I couldn't understand it well.

Comment: How about forgetting about the viewContainerRef completely? You do not need to take control of rendering the objects in that depth. What I was suggesting is to use other methods for binding your components (@ViewChildren for instance) and reorder your component array and let angular take care of the rendering. Other that that, I am afraid I can't help you.

Comment: see my example on the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I found no difference in your plunker and answer. I couldn't find the method you suggested with @ViewChildren. I am afraid I couldn't find what I have searched for in your plunker.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this, but reading the docs sounds like `move` is not the correct method.  Sounds like move is for "adding" an existing component to the view.

From the docs for `detach`:

> Use along with insert to move a View within the current container.

Based on that line, I'd try ...

```
let ref = this.location.viewContainerRef;
ref.detach(ref.indexOf(componentRef.hostView));
ref.insert(componentRef.hostView, 0);
```

**Edit**
I created a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ncg522?file=src/app/ad-banner.component.ts) using Angular's live example for [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

Here's the code relevant to the question:

```
// ShaneCoder - don't clear so we get multiple ads to demonstrate move.
// viewContainerRef.clear();

// ShaneCoder - only create 4 ads
if (viewContainerRef.length<4) {

    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;

    // ShaneCoder ad is inserted at the bottom (no index parameter).  Move it up if there are multiple ads.
    if (viewContainerRef.length>=1) {
        // we're not the first ad
        // move new ad to top using detach and insert (the next two lines answer the original question) 
        viewContainerRef.detach(viewContainerRef.indexOf(componentRef.hostView));
        viewContainerRef.insert(componentRef.hostView, 0);
        // comment out the previous two lines to see that ads are inserted at the bottom.
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

After posting the last edit realized I hadn't tried `move`.  Switched the `detach` and `insert` out for a `move` and it works.  [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ncg522-vpyznw?file=src/app/ad-banner.component.ts) here.    Relevant code:

```
viewContainerRef.move(componentRef.hostView, 0);
// comment out the previous two lines to see that ads are inserted at the bottom.
```

Now I'm wondering if the problem you were fighting with `move` was its zero-index.  To make a component the first in a container view you need to pass a zero for the index.  To make it second pass a one and so on.  So your code would change like such:

```
this.location.viewContainerRef.move(componentRef.hostView, 0);
```

Comment: suggest any method with practical implementation to interchange the components with the existing methods like move, detach or insert. I'll offer you this bounty. Only one hour left for bounty to expire.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting two different methods for interchanging the components in the container and for valuable time and effort.